# Accessing UI Thread or Main Thread from External class implementing Runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I hate `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread, skipped XXX frames`.. warning, Also it degrades the users UI interaction experience. So trying it with proper way as android wants it to be...

---

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    public Button StartBg;
    private static final String TAG = "TASK_FIRST";
    private Handler mainHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StartBg = findViewById(R.id.StartBg);

        StartBg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                ExampleRunner ExampleRunnerObj = new ExampleRunner(50000);
                new Thread(ExampleRunnerObj).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

When i keeps below class as inner class of `MainActivity`, It is able to access UI Components.

---

ExampleRunner :

```
public class ExampleRunner implements Runnable
{
    int count;

    public ExampleRunner(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Handler threadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"PERFORMING : "+i+"\n");

            if(i == 25000)
            {
                threadHandler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        // StartBg.setText("50k");
                        // OR RETURN SOMETHING..
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

But when i makes `ExampleRunner` as separate external class, it says `StartBg` can not be resolved...

So, How should I :

1. Make external java class which implements Runnable, Access Main Threads UI components...?
2. Or At least return something to mainActivity where i am starting it, so that from mainActivity i can access it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the external class the `Button` as a reference:

```
public class ExampleRunner implements Runnable
{
    int count;
    Button startBg;

    public ExampleRunner(int count, Button startBg) {
    this.count = count;
    this.startBg = startBg;
}
```

and create it with it:

```
ExampleRunner ExampleRunnerObj = new ExampleRunner(50000, StartBg);
```

then it will be able to use it in `run()`.

Right now, the `ExampleRunner` is an anonymous class accessing the `StargBg` variable declared locally.

Comment: Can we pass ui components as we do pass variables too...?? Is it that only?

Comment: Yes ui components are the variables of the class only.. It perfectly answers the question. Accept and Up vote

Answer (score 0):

If, I right understood you, for your solution, `AsyncTask` it is good solution.

Check docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask